# Abort immediately remaining threads in block

Tags: cuda

Is it possible to **immediately** exit from all remaining threads within single block when one of them is finding interesting result and there is no need to run them futher ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only in-kernel immediate exit is via [assertion](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#assertion) which is really intended for debugging purposes, and has significant side-effect.

There's no other way to do it from within a kernel -- you must use another method such as a variable that all threads are polling, or some other programmatic mechanism to tell all threads to exit.

Comment: OK. I was hoping for some "magic" function for that. I understand that some shared variable would be sufficient for that, however what about warp scheduling ? As I understand threads are grouped into warps that are being executed by threads proccessor. I can imagine that some threads are still waiting to be run when result is already found. My only best guess is to put condition for this shared variable into begin of kernel.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski: Have a look at the warp voting instructions, they give you a warp wide `any` or `all` operation which you can use to early exit code at a warp level (and two levels of those with a small shared memory array can get you block level early exit in a handful of instructions.